# Unable to authenticate against Azure DevOps _apis/distributedtask/variablegroups using PAT

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, base64, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm running a simple call to Azure DevOps API using Powershell:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "{USER}","{PAT}")))
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{ORG_NAME}/{PROJECT_NAME}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{ID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

The error is shown after:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Trying to figure out what's wrong, all is configured according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) articles.

The strange is that running a call against API without specifying the project is processed without errors:

```
$url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/{ORG_NAME}/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0" 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Response:

```
count value
----- -----
    5 {@{id=xxxxxxx-89f3-46b0-af7e-xxxxxxx; name=Xxxxx; description=F…
```

Comment: Looks like they are only base64 encoding the username [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#q-how-can-i-use-a-pat-in-my-code) and then putting the PAT token in after the colon. `The resulting string can then be provided as an HTTP header in the following format:
Authorization: Basic BASE64USERNAME:PATSTRING`. The C# examples then go on to provide an empty string for the username. Couple of things to try.

Comment: Hmm, not sure as I tried first to use only encoded PAT token and there was an error. After switching to full encoding (username:PAT) I was able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your PAT is not authorized to access the **Variable groups**.

You can go to your **PAT edit page** to check if the PAT was assigned at least the **Read** permission for **Variable groups**. See below screenshot.

Grant the proper permission scope for your PAT, and try calling the rest api again.

[image]

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't aware of such precise tailoring of PATs. Thanks.